# Serving html and javascript through structured Express app

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am currently playing with Express and attempting to solve (what I believe should be) a trivial problem.

I've got the following directory structure:

```
   |-config
   |---config.js
   |---routes.js
   |-server.js
   |-scripts
   |---controllers
   |------controllers.js
   |---directives
   |---filters
   |---services
   |---templates
   |---app.js
   |-views
   |---index.html
```

My server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

require('./config/config.js')(app);
require('./config/routes.js')(app);

app.listen(7777);
```

My config.js

```
module.exports = function(app){
    app.set('views', __dirname + '../views');
    app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
}
```

My routes.js

```
module.exports = function(app, express){

    app.get('/', function(reg, res){
        res.render('index.html')
    })

    app.use(function(err, req, res, next){
        console.error(err.stack);
        res.send(500, 'Something broke!');
    });
}
```

And finally my index.html

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.min.js'>
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    Hello World!!!
</body>
</html>
```

When I visit localhost:7000/

I get

```
Error: Failed to lookup view "index.html"
    at Function.app.render (/Users/abe/github/leap-motion-signature-recognition/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:494:17)
    at ServerResponse.res.render (/Users/abe/github/leap-motion-signature-recognition/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:756:7)
    at /Users/abe/github/leap-motion-signature-recognition/config/routes.js:7:13
    at callbacks (/Users/abe/github/leap-motion-signature-recognition/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:161:37)
    at param (/Users/abe/github/leap-motion-signature-recognition/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:135:11)
    at pass (/Users/abe/github/leap-motion-signature-recognition/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:142:5)
    at Router._dispatch (/Users/abe/github/leap-motion-signature-recognition/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:170:5)
    at Object.router (/Users/abe/github/leap-motion-signature-recognition/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:33:10)
    at next (/Users/abe/github/leap-motion-signature-recognition/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:190:15)
    at Object.expressInit [as handle] (/Users/abe/github/leap-motion-signature-recognition/node_modules/express/lib/middleware.js:30:5)
```

Why is that? Shouldn't the `__dirName` `set` have hooked `views\index.html`?

Secondly, I am planning to use this server to back an Angular JS app with many javascript files. What is the Express answer to the Rails asset pipeline? How can I include entire directories painlessly, without explicit population of `script` tags, and, if at all possible with deploy time minification?

Comment: Change `__dirname + '../views'` to `__dirname + '/../views'`.

Comment: You can serve static files from a directory with the [static middleware](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.use).

Comment: You can use the [exprses-uglify](https://github.com/ncrohn/express-uglify) middleware to minify your javascript files.

Comment: Thank you for your fantastic amount of help. If your write it up, I'll accept and upvote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`__dirname` has no trailing slash, so you should change `__dirname + '../views'` to `__dirname + '/../views'`.

You can serve static files from a directory with the [static middleware](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.use):

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/scripts'));
```

[express-uglify](https://github.com/ncrohn/express-uglify) can minify your javascript files:

```
var expressUglify = require('express-uglify');
app.use(expressUglify.middleware({ src: __dirname + '/scripts' }));
```